# If no packet in air, why pcap_next_ex() is not returning anything?

Tags: winpcap, sniffer

I am working on a sniffer. I am using WinPcap library in it. I am using a pcap_next_ex API to get the packets, I am calling this is in a infinite loop from the  from application. When I configure sniffer in 56 channel, there are no packets in air, so this API is not returning anything. so that application is hanging. Why it is not returning anything?

Comment: do you check the return code of `pcab_next_ex`? if so, maybe the timeout set in `pcap_open_live` is reached. Regarding the application hanging, I suggest that you spawn a separate thread for your listener

Comment: here issue is program is strucking at pcap_next_ex() line. not returning any status. i specified readout time as 1000 ms in pcap_open_live.